# Coded UI Test: The test run will not open a simple menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

I am being asked to evaluate Visual Studio for our automation testing efforts.
I have chosen to create a simple Coded UI Test where I simply want to open up Minesweeper (Win7 version), play with the custom game options and then close the application.

Every time I Run the test, it will not open the 'Game' menu item.

```
// Click 'Game' -> 'Options F5' menu item
Mouse.Click(uIOptionsF5MenuItem, new Point(26, 6));
```

Now, if I myself click the menu item (basically giving the test a 'push'), the automation takes over by selecting the menu option I need and then will run without any issue. I just can't figure out why the test can not open this menu on its own. I've tried the SetFocus method already and I haven't found any other options. The MSDN documentation offers ZERO help.

Anyone have an idea how I can get this menu to open?

```
Result Message: 
Test method Blorg.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1 threw exception: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException: The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties. Additional Details: 
TechnologyName:  'MSAA'
ControlType:  'MenuItem'
Name:  'Options F5'
```

Comment: Starting programs from the Windows Start menu did not work for me. I think I managed it by creating a desktop shortcut to the program, then recording a double-click on the desktop icon.

Comment: What search properties are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the menu item and perform the click like this,

```
WinMenuItem uIOptionsF5MenuItem = new WinMenuItem(Add the window where the menu is placed) {TechnologyName="MSAA" };
uIOptionsF5MenuItem.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "Options F5");
Mouse.Click(uIOptionsF5MenuItem);
```